# How to drop all empty/invalid partitions of an external table in hive at once

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I have a table with multiple partitions. I have deleted few partition records in hdfs. How can I drop all the empty partitions in the corresponding hive table at once.

Comment: "I have deleted few partition records in hdfs" - does it mean you deleted partition folders?

Comment: Yes, i have deleted few partitions(partition folders) in hdfs. Let's say i have total of 10 partitions in a table, i have now deleted 4 of those partitions in hdfs, is there a query to drop all the empty partitions?? Without mentioning the partition value in the hive query.